# How to open Excel in windows 10 at the background without "Save as"

Tags: c#, excel, windows-10-desktop

This code opens excel at the background with no issue on windows 7 and 8, however on windows 10 it pops out with "save as" prompt. Do you have any idea how can I get rid of "Save as" prompt?

```
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
xlApp = new Excel.Application();
//xlApp.Visible = false; // this does not help to get rid of save as
//xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false; // this does not help to get rid of save as
//xlApp.ScreenUpdating = false; // this does not help to get rid of save as
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(excelFileURL, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
excelWorkbook.SaveAs(excelFileURL, AccessMode: Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive);
```

Answer (score 0):

Save as pops out during closing of excel on Office 2016
It is not related to Windows 10

To close without "save as" promt

```
xlWorkBook.Close(false, misValue, misValue);
```